# Reducing database access time and connection count

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework

I have 2 connections. How can I reduce this to one connection?

```
//AuthentificationController class:
    public string Register(string nickName, string email, string password)
    {
       try
       {
          if(!UserWorker.IsUserRegistered(nickName)) //connect
          {
             UserWorker.RegisterUser(nickName, email, password)) //connect
             return "Done";
          }
          else
          {
             return "You are already registered";
          }
       }
       catch(Exception ex)
       {
          //log
          return "Server error";
       }
    }

//UserWorker class:
    //...
    bool IsUserRegistered(string nickName)
    {
         using(var context = new XContext)
         {
              return context.Users.Contains(x => x.NickName == nickName);
         }
    }

    //...
    void RegisterUser(string nickName, string email, string password)
    {
         using(var context = new XContext)
         {
              User newUser = new User(nickName, email, password);
              context.Users.Add(newUser);
              context.SaveChanges();
         }
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it's a bit hard to review code like this because the code you are showing is example code rather than code that you're actually using in a real project, which means that a lot of context has been stripped away. Unlike Stack Overflow, we prefer to look at real code instead of example code. Please see the meta question: [Why is hypothetical code off-topic for Code Review?](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/1709/41243)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as *example code*, because it has been stripped down of its context and wouldn't compile as is (`var context = new XContext` isn't valid C#). That said, you're using two *contexts*, that doesn't mean you're using two *connections* - you may want to read up on connection pooling and how EF is handling that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I only see one connection. you should only have one method that registers the user. I mean that `Register` and `RegisterUser` are the same thing.

This :

> ```
> public string Register(string nickName, string email, string password)
> {
>    try
>    {
>       if(!UserWorker.IsUserRegistered(nickName)) //connect
>       {
>          UserWorker.RegisterUser(nickName, email, password)) //connect
>          return "Done";
>       }
>       else
>       {
>          return "You are already registered";
>       }
>    }
>    catch(Exception ex)
>    {
>       //log
>       return "Server error";
>    }
> }
>
> //...
> bool IsUserRegistered(string nickName)
> {
>      using(var context = new XContext)
>      {
>           return context.Users.Contains(x => x.NickName == nickName);
>      }
> }
>
> //...
> void RegisterUser(string nickName, string email, string password)
> {
>      using(var context = new XContext)
>      {
>           User newUser = new User(nickName, email, password);
>           context.Users.Add(newUser);
>           context.SaveChanges();
>      }
> }
> ```

should be

```
public string Register(string nickName, string email, string password)
{
    try
    {
        if(!UserWorker.IsUserRegistered(nickName)) //connect
        {
            using(var context = new XContext)
            {
                User newUser = new User(nickName, email, password);
                context.Users.Add(newUser);
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
            return "Done";
        }
        else
        {
            return "You are already registered";
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        //log
        return "Server error";
    }
}

//...
bool IsUserRegistered(string nickName)
{
     using(var context = new XContext)
     {
          return context.Users.Contains(x => x.NickName == nickName);
     }
}
```

Or better yet, you should get rid of the boolean as well and only use 1 `context` for the entire thing

```
public string Register(string nickName, string email, string password)
{
    try
    {
        using(var context = new XContext)
        {
            if (context.Users.Contains(x => x.NickName == nickName)
            {
                User newUser = new User(nickName, email, password);
                context.Users.Add(newUser);
                context.SaveChanges();
                return "Done";
            }
            else
            {
                return "You are already registered";
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        //log
        return "Server error";
    }
}
```

Comment: Register - class in AuthentificationController
IsUserRegistered and RegisterUser - it is methods of UserWorker class

Comment: I am not following?  can you change the methods? if you can't why are you asking us to help you change code that you can't change?